# Running this Haskell code in Powershell does nothing

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell for a school project and am going through Hudak's *Haskell School of Expression*. I have written the following test code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = return ()

p :: Float
p = 3.14159

totalArea :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
totalArea r1 r2 r3 =
    let 
        circleArea r = p*r^2 
    in
        circleArea (fromIntegral r1) + circleArea (fromIntegral r2) + circleArea (fromIntegral r3)
```

This compiles fine, but how do I actually run it? I type into Powershell `./test.exe totalArea 5 6 7`, and nothing happens. I know this is a total noob question, so I'm sorry in advance and thanks for the help!

Comment: `main = return ()`, so that means the program is not doing anything: you just defined a constant and function, but you do not do anything with these.

Comment: You can write `main = print (totalArea 5 6)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main = return ()`, so that means the program is not doing anything: you just defined a constant and function, but you do not do anything with these.

You can implement the `main` to print the result of `totalArea 5 6 7`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (testArea 5 6 7)
```

or for example parse program parameters:

```
import System.Environment(getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (ra : rb : rc : _) <- getArgs
    print (testArea (read ra) (read rb) (read rc))
```

then you can call the program with:

```
./test.exe 5 6 7
```

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. But is there anyway to read in the variables in the command line?

Comment: @Manfredian: see edit to parse the three integer parameters.